# Fluent nhibernate : Problems when deleting a HasOne relationship

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys

I have two classes

```
public  PartMap()
{
   Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
   HasOne(x => x.Stock)
          .Cascade.All();
}

public Stock
{
  Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Guid();
  References(x => x.Part);
}
```

Part has only one stock, that's the reason i used HasOne.
The data is inserted ok, I have a part , a stock and they are saved ok.
My problem is when trying to delete I get an error that the stock foreing key to part was violated

```
"ORA-02292: integrity constraint (PRINERGY.FK121AD9E59966BE23) violated " .
```

I see the it tries to delete the part without deleting the related stock before.
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 7):

It seems like a one-to-one bidirectional association. There are two ways how to map this association in NH (and FNH): primary key association and foreign key association. Your example is closer to foreign key association.

**Foreign key association**

```
public PartMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    References(x => x.Stock).Unique().Cascade.All();
    Map(x => x.Name);
}

public StockMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    HasOne(x => x.Part).Cascade.All().PropertyRef("Stock");
    Map(x => x.Name);
}
```

**Primary key association**

```
public PartMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Guid();
    HasOne(x => x.Stock).Cascade.All();
    Map(x => x.Name);
}

public StockMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Part");
    HasOne(x => x.Part).Constrained();
    Map(x => x.Name);
}
```

For more details see http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/03/conform-mapping-one-to-one.html.

Comment: Which version did you use? And could you please mark this answer as solved?:)

Comment: After two days of researching I have found this answer. I would like to give you milion points for this :)